# I am having trouble changing my images on click event with Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, onclick, swap, src

I am trying to swap image when an image is clicked...here is my jquery so far and it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
imgFldr = '../../App_Themes/Default/Images/';
    $('#smallImg1').click(function(){

        $('#smallImg1').attr('src', imgFlder+'belkinSmall4.png');
    });
});
```

And below is an example of my HTML

```
<div>
     <img id="smallImg1" src="../../App_Themes/Default/Images/belkinSmall1.png" />
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try setting the img source to ../../App_Themes/Default/Images/belkinSmall4.png in html and see if the image shows that way, if it doesn't then its your directory you have the source set to.

Answer (score 1):

I would have written it like this:

```
$(function() {
  var imageFolder = '../../App_Themes/Default/Images/';
  $('#smallImg1').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', imageFolder + "belkinSmall4.png");
  });
});
```

- `$(function() { ... })` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`
- `imageFolder` instead of `imgFldr`. Pointless abbreviation imo.
- `var imageFolder`, too (`var` is the key here), so that it is a local variable, not a global.
- `$(this)` instead of `$('#smallImg1')`, to avoid duplications. The result is identical.

However, this is just a re-factoring of your code — both your snippet and mine should work.

So, "doesn't work" - does the image change? Is the path invalid? Do you get any JS runtime errors? What if you set the src to `'../../App_Themes/Default/Images/belkinSmall4.png'` by hand — does the image exist?